# SQL Add Values from 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sum, union, addition

I need to add the uniqueid and WBid from both tables. With my input below, I get the correct data from both tables, but it just lists it in rows, and doesn't sum it.

```
select distinct COUNT(l.uniqueid), SUM(r.WBid), l.uniqueid, l.firstname, ``l.lastname,       l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city  FROM EDW..lookupuser l 
INNER JOIN DB..DimBD b on b.userid = l.userId
INNER JOIN DB..FactVP v on v.BidderId = b.bidderid
INNER JOIN DB..FactRD r on r.buyerid = b.bidderid
and r.AuctionDate > '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY l.uniqueid, l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city, l.firstname, l.lastname

UNION 
select distinct COUNT(l.uniqueid), SUM(t.WBid), l.uniqueid, l.firstname, l.lastname,     l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city  FROM EDW..lookupuser l
INNER JOIN DB..DimB b on b.userid = l.userId
INNER JOIN DB..FactVP v on v.BidderId = b.bidderid
INNER JOIN DB..FactTA t on t.BidderId = b.bidderid
and t.AuctionDate > '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY l.uniqueid, l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city, l.firstname, l.lastname
order by l.email asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the union first and them SUM it. Otherwise you would get two sets of results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(uniqueid), SUM(WBid), uniqueid, firstname, lastname, email, phone, mobile, address, city
FROM (
   SELECT l.uniqueid, r.WBid, l.uniqueid, l.firstname, ``l.lastname, l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city
   FROM EDW..lookupuser l
   INNER JOIN DB..DimBD b ON b.userid = l.userId
   INNER JOIN DB..FactVP v ON v.BidderId = b.bidderid
   INNER JOIN DB..FactRD r ON r.buyerid = b.bidderid AND r.AuctionDate > '2012-12-31'

   UNION

   SELECT l.uniqueid, t.WBid, l.uniqueid, l.firstname, l.lastname, l.email, l.phone, l.mobile, l.address, l.city
   FROM EDW..lookupuser l
   INNER JOIN DB..DimB b ON b.userid = l.userId
   INNER JOIN DB..FactVP v ON v.BidderId = b.bidderid
   INNER JOIN DB..FactTA t ON t.BidderId = b.bidderid AND t.AuctionDate > '2012-12-31'
   ) x
GROUP BY uniqueid, email, phone, mobile, address, city, firstname, lastname
ORDER BY email ASC
```